# Angular: event listener no longer triggered when I move mouse off component

Tags: angular, addeventlistener, event-listener, window-object

I have a context menu in my Angular app, and I want to trigger a callback whenever a key is pressed while that context menu is open. I added the following code inside the constructor of my context menu:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  console.log('keys pressed');
});
```

If I open the context menu, hover the cursor over it, and press a key, it successfully triggers this callback. However, if I move the mouse *off* the menu, it no longer triggers it when I press a key. Moreover, even if I move the mouse back over the menu, it still doesn't respond. I want it to respond when I press a key no matter where the cursor is, as long as the context menu is open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a minimal verifiable code example? Maybe a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      console.log('keys pressed');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need keyDown and click event to properly listen context menu events. the complete code can be founded here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tpa4m)

Your component code is..

```
contextmenu:boolean = false;
styleSelect: boolean = false;

clickMe(){
   this.contextmenu = !this.contextmenu;
   this.styleSelect === true ? this.styleSelect= false : '';
   document.addEventListener('keydown', this.scroll, false );
}

scroll = (e): void => {
     if (e.target.tagName === 'LI' ) {document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.scroll); }
     if (this.contextmenu === true) {
        this.contextmenu = false;
        this.styleSelect = true;
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.scroll);
     }
 }

 close(){
   this.contextmenu = false;
 }
```